# Downloading data sets from Common Voice using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I am trying to write a script that downloads data sets from Mozilla's Common Voice and separate the files into different folders for a project. I am using the requests package with the code

```
response = requests.get(common_voice_url)
```

However, this is giving me a 403 error. I see that to download from Common Voice, you would need to input your email and check two boxes for two agreements. How can I update my code to pass in these information?

I have tried passing in my email this way:

```
email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
data = {'email': email}
response = requests.post(common_voice_url, data=data)
```

However, this now gives a 400 error.

One more detail is, if I run the download function in a separate test.py, it works as intended. But if I run the entire script (download->unzip->separate into folders->etc.) as a click command, it runs in to the problem mentioned above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on what URL you're trying to access. Your second attempt also seems to be POSTing rather than GETting, which is odd for a request to download information that isn't trying to modify any state or create anything.